# Combine data from multiple lists of different length

Tags: python, list, loops, python-3.6

I have a db query returning three sets of data. It comes in this format.

```
year = (('Adison', '355', 4), ('windsor windham', '455', 6), ('windham', '655', 2), ('btown', '233', 5))
month = (('Adison', '355', 2), ('windham', '655', 1))
week = (('btown', '233', 8), ('Adison', '355', 9))
```

The year list is always the longest with the most values. I need to take the last value from each element in the month and week lists and append them to the year list in their proper spot, based on the town.

IF there is not a corresponding value in month or week, I need to append a 0. Ideally making it look like this:

```
year = (('Adison', '355', 4, 2, 9), ('windsor windham', '455', 6, 0, 0), ('windham', '655', 2, 1, 0), ('btown', '233', 5, 0, 8))
```

I have tried putting two lists in a for loop and using an `if in` conditional to check values but I think I am overlooking something and am getting index errors. I tried something like this:

```
for each in year:
    for part in month:
        if part in each:
            each.append(part[-1])
        else:
            each.append(0)
```

I know there has to be a better way, and one that actually works to accomplish this. Is there a tool or module I should be looking into?  I have played with `zip` but because they are not the same length I am having trouble. Thank You!

***EDIT***

I understand that I have tuples above, In my code a convert them all to list objects before modifying. Also I am on Python 3.6

Comment: Which python version are you on?

Comment: I am using 3.6.

Comment: Python tuples are immutable, so they don't have an `.append` method. You have to do stuff like `new_tuple = old_tuple + ('more', 'data')`

Comment: I know in my real code I converted them all to lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, key a dict off of the first two elements, using zeros as default for month and week.  Then fill in the month and week, if necessary:

```
data = {(name, n): [y, 0, 0] for name, n, y in year}

for name, n, m in month:
    data[name, n][1] = m

for name, n, w in week:
    data[name, n][2] = w

data = tuple(tuple([*k, *v]) for k, v in data.items())
```

Answer (score 2):

You can build dicts from the `month` and `week` tuples and fetch values from those to create new *sub*-tuples appending the new values. Using `dict.get(..., 0)` allows to set a default 0 for cities that do not have month or week data:

```
dct_mth = {k: v for k, _, v in month}
dct_week = {k: v for k, _, v in week}

year = list(year)  # make container mutable
for i, yr in enumerate(year):
    year[i] += (dct_mth.get(yr[0], 0), dct_week.get(yr[0], 0))

print(year)
# [('Adison', '355', 4, 2, 9), ('windsor windham', '455', 6, 0, 0), ('windham', '655', 2, 1, 0), ('btown', '233', 5, 0, 8)]
```

Comment: I don't know how I got it wrong here but It is just appending 0's to each list not actually updating with values

Comment: @Joe Make sure the dictionary keys actually contain the same strings as in `year`.

Answer (score 0):

Is this useful ?

```
year = [['Adison', '355', 4],['windsor windham', '455', 6],
        ['windham', '655', 2],['btown', '233', 5]]

month = [['Adison', 355, 2],['windham', '655', 1]]

week = [['btown', '233', 8],['Adison', '355', 9]]

for y in year:
  for m in month:
    if y[0] == m[0]:
      y.append(m[-1])
  for w in week:
    if y[0] == w[0]:
      y.append(w[-1])

for each in year:
  print(each)
```

> ['Adison', '355', 4, 2, 9]
>
> ['windsor windham', '455', 6]
>
> ['windham','655', 2, 1]
>
> ['btown', '233', 5, 8]

Answer (score 0):

The code below first converts the data to dicts, and then combines the data from the month & week dicts into the year dict. Finally, it converts the combined data to a list of tuples.

I'm using dicts because it's much faster to look up items by their key in a dict than to scan through a list or tuple, item by item, looking for matches. It doesn't make much difference when there's only a handful of items, but if your real data has dozens or hundreds of towns, the speed difference would be huge.

I assume the number following the town name is some kind of ID code so that we can have multiple towns with the same name but different ID numbers. Thus my dicts use the name and that number as the key.

```
year = (('Adison', '355', 4), ('windsor windham', '455', 6), ('windham', '655', 2), ('btown', '233', 5))
month = (('Adison', '355', 2), ('windham', '655', 1))
week = (('btown', '233', 8), ('Adison', '355', 9))

# Convert a nested tuple to a dict, using the first 2 fields 
# in the tuple as the key and the last field as the value.
def make_dict(seq):
    return {u[:-1]: [u[-1]] for u in seq}

year = make_dict(year)
month = make_dict(month)
week = make_dict(week)

# Add the month & week data to the year data
for k in year:
    year[k] += month.get(k, [0]) + week.get(k, [0])
print(year)

# Convert the updated year dict to a list of tuples
data = []
for k, v in year.items():
    data.append(k + tuple(v))
for row in data:
    print(row)
```

**output**

```
{('Adison', '355'): [4, 2, 9], ('windsor windham', '455'): [6, 0, 0], ('windham', '655'): [2, 1, 0], ('btown', '233'): [5, 0, 8]}
('Adison', '355', 4, 2, 9)
('windsor windham', '455', 6, 0, 0)
('windham', '655', 2, 1, 0)
('btown', '233', 5, 0, 8)
```

If you want `data` to be a tuple of tuples, just do `data = tuple(data)`. OTOH, the dict form is probably more useful than a list.